# Angular/Material mat-datepicker does not show in proper location

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, material-design, angular-flex-layout

I am utilizing Fuse theme for an angular website. here is the layout:

```
<div class="content p-24">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayout.gt-md="row" fxFlex="50">
            <form class="mat-white-bg mat-elevation-z4 p-24 mr-24 mb-24" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxFlex="1 0 auto"
              name="form" [formGroup]="form">
    ...
              <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="100">
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a Start date" (dateChange)="startDateChange()"
                    formControlName="start">
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
    ....
    ...
    </div>
    </div>
```

However the datepicker picker is not showing in the right location on the page, it appears far off to the right of the page as it is %100 width:
[image]

Any ideas how to take to where it belongs?

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend to use `touchUi` flag to show in the middle of the screen. it will save more time for adjusting date picker popup.

```html
<mat-form-field fxFlex="100">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a Start date" (dateChange)="startDateChange()" formControlName="start">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```